# Netty UDP DatagramPacket deserialization?

Tags: netty

In server use proto UDP to send POJO serializable, but in client how to deserialize the UDP DatagramPacket with netty?

Answer (score 1):

Just Extends this Handler

```
abstract public class BaseChannelInboundHandler<D> extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket datagramPacket) throws Exception {
    try {
        ByteBuf buf = datagramPacket.content();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
        buf.readBytes(bytes);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        Object obj = inputStream.readObject();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        D d = (D) obj;
        messageReceived(ctx, d);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FLog.e(e);
    }
}

abstract protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, D data);
```

}